# Latest WP breaks CSS in PHP7

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am experiencing a weird issue in WP dashboard with the latest version of Wordpress. I think I have figured out what is happening, but I don't know how to figure out why and how to fix it.

Whenever I am in the WP dashboard everything seems to be working fine, until I'm going into Post edit or media upload, then the whole CSS and JS breaks and I see all of the content in Times New Roman.

This issue does not happen on the test server which is running PHP 5.6.10 while the new server the site is supposed to be at, is running PHP 7.

This issue does not happen if I downgrade the Wordpress version to 4.7.3.

The site is running latest Wordpress (4.7.5) and the theme is OnePress 1.3.6

View source - WP dashboard: http://pasted.co/ba9b8ca5

View source - WP post edit: http://pasted.co/8c273ddd

Comment: Image of the issue: http://imgur.com/gallery/IafjZ

Comment: Any error on the client or server side?

Comment: Check your browser's web inspector for errors in the console tab.

Comment: No errors in the console tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: And I have reinstalled Wordpress several times.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache error logs for errors. Your stylesheet is returning a blank white screen: http://trilobite-microsystems.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load[]=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,widgets,site-icon,&load[]=l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.7.5

Comment: I see no difference between this one: http://dintp.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,buttons,media-views,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menu&load%5B%5D=s,widgets,site-icon,l10n,wp-auth-check&ver=4.7.5

and this one: http://trilobite-microsystems.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load[]=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,widgets,site-icon,&load[]=l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.7.5